# How to maintain multiple versions of Non-REST APIs in CakePHP 2

Tags: php, api, cakephp-2.0

**Scenario:** 
I have an existing CakePHP 2.8 application with web frontend and a set of APIs to support apps on mobile platforms(Android and iOS for now).
The problem is the APIs are not RESTful and I need to update the web and write a new version for the APIs (with lots of database changes) while providing support for the old ones.
For some functionalities, there are common actions which give platform specific response by detecting the origin of request(mobile platforms send a header for this) while for some functionalities, there are separate actions for web and app.
Please suggest some approach on how to achieve this while not breaking the existing APIs and what changes should I do to make this maintainable in future.
Many Thanks